How to read the sequence chart of mpu6050?
click the link jump to view the sequence char
It's page 18 in the PDF: "MPU-6000 and MPU-6050 Product Specification".
My code of the register's R&W through I2C are as follows:

void MPU6050_WriteReg(uint8_t RegAddress, uint8_t Data)
{
    MyI2C_Start();
    MyI2C_SendByte(MPU6050_ADDRESS);
    MyI2C_ReceiveAck();
    MyI2C_SendByte(RegAddress);
    MyI2C_ReceiveAck();
    MyI2C_SendByte(Data);
    MyI2C_ReceiveAck();
    MyI2C_Stop();
}

uint8_t MPU6050_ReadReg(uint8_t RegAddress)
{
    uint8_t Data;

    MyI2C_Start();
    MyI2C_SendByte(MPU6050_ADDRESS);
    MyI2C_ReceiveAck();
    MyI2C_SendByte(RegAddress);
    MyI2C_ReceiveAck();

    MyI2C_Start();
    MyI2C_SendByte(MPU6050_ADDRESS | 0x01);
    MyI2C_ReceiveAck();
    Data = MyI2C_ReceiveByte();
    MyI2C_SendAck(1);
    MyI2C_Stop();

    return Data;
}







‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍
